# could gSoap be integrated with the Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gsoap

We are using GAE to host our web services, as far as I know GAE only support Java and python at the moment, however most of our engineers here are more comfortable with C/C++, so i was wondering if there is a way to integrate gsoap with GAE at all. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Though I am not an expert at Google App Engine, it is unlikely you'd be able to use native C++ code in the app engine.  Based on experience with an app engine like Tomcat, the purpose of application engines is to make your application run on a shared service in its own little sandbox so that it can't affect the other shared services.  With C++, you can  get a pointer to the beginning of the process memory and start writing zeros if you so desired.  This doesn't turn out to work too well in a shared computing environment.

The app engine pages indicate Java and Python runtime environments are available. I've been using C++ for many years and am a big fan of gSoap, but I think these are tools best used in limited cases these days.  Web services for Java aren't that much different from gSoap in terms of ramp-up time anyway.

I've used Axis2 for Java web services and it isn't that difficult to use.  However, I think it suffers from being overly complex and under documented.  I have used WSO2 under PHP and was impressed with how easy it was to use.  WSO2 is built on top of Axis and has a Java port too (though I have not used it).  If your engineers want to dig in, WSO2 is probably going to be the easiest route.

Motivating them might be hard, but my take is that if they are real software engineers then they won't have a problem adapting.

This might be helpful too: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No, Google-App engine is very limited with what you can do (you can't even dynamically create new files).